# How is loop gain related to the complete transfer function?

Tags: analog, control-system, transfer-function, negative-feedback

I am trying to understand how the loop gain of a system determines the stability of a complete system.

Loop gain is given by 1+GH where G is the forward transfer function (TF) and H is the feedback factor.

If we make the loop gain stable, then how it is possible that my transfer function is also stable? Because the poles of H become the zeros of the transfer function, so the complete system response changes.

How I can determine the transfer function shape from the loop gain/characteristic equation?

[image]

Comment: *If we make loop gain stable...* It is not the **loopgain** that is stable/unstable. It is the **system including feedback** (for example an opamp + feedback resistors) that is stable or not. The loopgain needs to have certain properties (like loopgain < 1 when phase approaches 180 degrees) in order to make the **system** stable. All this is explained in all textbooks that discuss **feedback**.

Comment: Also you might want to have a look at: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/negative-feedback-part-4-introduction-to-stability/#:~:text=The%20Loop%20Gain&text=In%20this%20context%2C%20a%20closed,analysis%20is%20the%20loop%20gain. Also the ebook I always recommend about opamps, "Opamps for everyone" has a chapter on stability: https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf  see chapter 5.

Comment: Loop-gain is an open-loop measurement and hence is inherently stable.

Comment: Loop gain is equal to GH not (1 + GH). Or the purists might reason that loop gain is equal to -GH when the complete loop is taken into account. H is the feedback fraction which is often and very confusingly referred to as the feedback factor. I try to reserve the term "feedback factor" for the factor 1+GH.

Comment: @James...According to Harold Black the quantity H (he calls it "beta") is the "feedback circuit". And I think, in order to to mathematically treat this circuit we should identify this expression (H or beta) with its transfer function or transfer "factor" or simply feedback factor (because, in fact, it is the factor which defines the output portion that is fed back).. And for the denumerator (1+GH) some authors (Boris L. Lurie, in accordance with Bode) are using the term "return difference" .

Comment: @LvW I tend to refer to 1 + GH as the feedback factor because it represents the actual amount of feedback in the circuit where the feedback is not just the fraction of the output that is fed back but is a measure of how large the  input to the circuit is compared to the resulting input signal. For a non-inverting amplifier this would be Vin/Vdiff where Vdiff is the difference voltage between the inputs. This, as I understand it, is the real measure of the amount of feedback in the circuit - it is equal to 1 + GH (or 1 + beta*Ao) and represents the factor by which......

Comment: .... many of the characteristics of the amplifier are improved. eg. Distortion, output impedence etc.

Comment: @James...How can you say that the quantity "beta" (or in our discussion "H") would be "not just the fraction of the output that is fed back"? This is in contrast to most of the classical feedback schemes. We know that (1+GH)=(1+ loop gain) can be a rather large expression - why do you propose to define this expressionas "feedback factor"? For my opinion, it is better called "reduction factor" - applicable to gain, input/output resistances, distortion etc.

Comment: I didn't say H or beta would be "not just the fraction of the output fed back". H or beta  are the fraction of the output fed back, but "the fraction of the output fed back" and "the feedback" are two different things. Take a purely resistive feedback network, beta is a constant at all frequencies but the feedback or (1 + beta*Aol) will reduce with increasing frequency due to the dominant pole open loop gain roll off and that is why distortion and output resistance increase with increasing frequency - the feedback is reducing - the difference between the inputs is increasing with increasing..

Comment: .... frequency as the open loop gain rolls off reducing negative feedback. It is the amount of overall negative feedback that controls the amplifier's parameter improvement not just the fraction of the output fed back.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to say that the loop-gain must be stable in order for the complete, closed loop system, to be stable.

<sub>Note: in the system \$ F = \frac{G}{1+GH} \$, loop gain is \$GH\$, not \$1+GH\$, as you stated.</sub>

It *may* be true that instability in the path \$GH\$ could cause closed-loop instability (for example, if \$H\$ itself is an ill-behaved entity), but as you noted, \$GH\$ appears in the denominator of the closed loop transfer function, and any notion of stability pertaining to \$GH\$ in and of itself is rendered moot, once you close the loop.

Rather than aiming for stability in \$GH\$, you are more concerned with obtaining a magnitude and phase response of \$GH\$ with frequency that does not cause feedback to become simultaneousy positive with a gain of one or more at *any* frequency. In response to your question about determining the shape of \$GH\$, that is the main purpose of Bode plots, graphs of gain and phase vs. frequency, from which you can visually identify such conditions.

I think it's fair to say (although I am not certain that it is formally correct to say this), that those required conditions for phase and magitude of \$GH\$ (to obtain stability) correspond to the requirement that the complex roots of \$1+GH\$ all reside in the left half of the complex plane (they all have negative real parts).

The fact that the denominator of the closed loop transfer function is \$1+GH\$, as opposed to simply \$GH\$, means that the poles and zeroes of \$GH\$ *do not* become zeroes and poles respectively of the closed loop transfer function, although I imagine that this could be a reasonable approximation for certain instances of \$G\$ and \$H\$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a G of 1,000,000,000 at 500 degrees, at 100Hz. (actually the frequency does not matter).

Implement an H of 10 (or 100, or 1,000)

This will be stable, despite the huge phase shift. Why?

Running the math on this, we find

- The Numerator, of course, is 1,000,000,000 at 500 degrees phase shift
- The Denominator, of course (1 + G * H) = (1 + 1,000,000,000/_ 500 * 0.1)
  which becomes 100,000,001 /_ 500

and the combined transfer function is stable, because the phaseshifts cancel.

================================

Notice the mag/phase is nowhere near the Nyquist point.

Comment: H of 10 (or 100 or 1000)??? Or do you mean 1/10 or 1/100....?

Answer (score 0):

Quote: *If we make loop gain stable then how it is possible that my transfer function is also stable? because the poles of H becomes zeros of transfer function. So the complete systerm response changes?
How I can determine the transfer function shape from loop gain/Characteristic equation?*

In most cases, the loop gain (gain around the complete loop when it is open) is stable. But this does not mean that the closed-loop will also be stable. Stability properties (stability margin) must be checked using the stability criterion which can be applied in different ways: Bode diagram or Nyquist diagram or Nichols diagram).

It is to be noted that there are some rare cases where the lopp gain is NOT stable. In this case, the closed-loop can be made stable.

Concerning your last question:

- Yes, the system response changes when the loop is closed. In general, it is not possible to guess how the "shape" of the closed-loop transfer function (magnitude) will look like.
- However, in many cases this will be possible (approximately) when the gain of the forward function is pretty large (example: Operational amplifier) because in this case we have [G/(1+GH)]=1/[(1/G)+H] which equals 1/H for G>>1. Hence, the closed-loop function is just the inverse of the feedback function H.

Answer (score 0):

Take, for example, a non-invering amplifier with a beta equal to 0.1 (R1 = 1k, R2 = 9k) operating at a frequency where its open loop gain is equal to 10. Its noise gain = 1/beta = 10 and it is operating at its closed loop -3dB frequency because the open loop gain is equal to the noise gain. Therefore the closed loop gain is equal to 10 * 0.707 = 7.07. If Vin is 1V pk to pk the output voltage will be 7.07V pk to pk. The voltage across the lower arm resistor is equal to 7.07*0.1 = 0.707V pk to pk. The voltage between the amplifier's inputs, Vdiff will be (output voltage)/(open loop gain) = 7.07/10 = 0.707V pk to pk. The loop gain, with out the inversion which occurs in the open loop loop gain measurement, is equal to the voltage across the lower arm resistor divided by Vdiff = 0.707/0.707 = 1.

The feedback fraction is 0.1 and the overall negative feedback factor (1 + beta*Aol) = Vin/Vdiff =  1.414 (Assuming open loop phase lag is -90 degrees).

Also of interest may be the closed loop phase lag which is -45 degrees.

The loop gain is equal to 1 (unity) and because the feedback network is purely resistive it means that the loop phase is equal to the open loop phase which is approx -90 degrees. The phase margin is 180-90 = 90 degrees and therefore the amp is very stable.

Comment: Quote: "...the overall negative feedback factor (1 + beta*Aol) .....How can you say that this expression (you call it "feedback factor") would be NEGATIVE ? Instead, see what wikipedia says (Quote): "...the voltage gain of the amplifier with feedback, the closed-loop gain AFB, is derived in terms of the gain of the amplifier without feedback, the open-loop gain AOL and the feedback factor β, which governs how much of the output signal is applied to the input (see Figure 1)".

Comment: @LvW That Wikipedia quote is perfectly accurate - beta does govern how much of the output signal is applied to the input although I would have been happier if they had referred to beta as the feedback fraction because beta is not the only factor that determines how much the input signal is being reduced by.The amount that the input signal is being reduced by also depends on how big Vdiff is. If the amplifier is being used over the frequency range where the output is fairly constant then the fraction of the output being fed back will be fairly constant but vdiff will be increasing with .....

Comment: .... increasing frequency. The actual voltage into the amp Vdiff will become larger and larger fraction of Vin as frequency increases even though the magnitude of the voltage fed back is fairly constant.

Comment: @James...did you misunderstand my comments? Of course, Vdiff is not constant when the open-loop gain decreases. But this effect has nothing to do with my comment. It only concerns the definition of the feedback factor. I only have referenced the wikipedis definition for beta. There, the quantity "beta" is called "feedback factor" and the associated figure clearly shows what it is: It defines the feedback fraction that is fed back to the summing junction. Note that this factor must not necessarily be unitless. It can be V/I or I/V.

Comment: @LvW I was just trying to explain why I reserve the term "negative feedback factor" for (1+beta*Aol) as this factor best describes the negative feedback in the circuit whereas beta only describes the fraction of the output fed back.

Comment: OK. I accept that of course. I just wanted to make clear that your definition is not in line with the generally accepted definition used in practically all books and other knowledge sources (as far as I know).

Comment: Yes, I've seen beta called "feedback factor" all over the internet. I never was a great one for following the crowd! Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: @James....please, allow me one last comment/question: In case of beta=0 your definition makes the "feedback factor" (1+beta*Aol) equal to "1". How to interprete this result? Does this sound logical because there is no feedback path at all....

Comment: My feedback factor, (1+ beta*Aol) is a measure of how large Vin is compared to Vdiff, that is to say Vin/Vdiff. Ie. It is a measure of how much Vin is reduced to create the amplifier's actual input signal Vdiff. In the case of a non-inverting amplifier with beta = 0 there is no feedback from the output, the amplifier's negative input would be grounded and Vin would be equal to Vdiff. 100% of the circuit's input signal would be applied between the amplifier's inputs. The amplifier is operating open loop.

Comment: @James...I know what it means when beta=0. But this was not my question. Again: For beta=0 your feedback factor is "1" (although there is no feedback at all). I am afraid such a definition could create some confusion - in particular for beginners.  I rather think, a definition should be logical and support the understanding of equations and operating principles of circuits and systems. Sorry to say - but to me its not quite logical.

Comment: @LvW I have a question about your statement : "Therefore the closed loop gain is equal to 10 * 0.707 = 7.07" Non inverting amplifier gain is 1+R2/R1 = 10 (assuming Ao is very large). then how do you came to 7.07 ?

Comment: @Sitward 1+R2/R1 is the formula to calculate the dc or low frequency closed loop gain. As frequency increases the closed loop gain reduces, slowly at first but more quickly at higher frequencies. At the frequency where the noise gain (1+R2/R1) is equal to the open loop gain, the closed loop gain will be reduced by 3dB from its dc value or from 10 down to 7.07.

Comment: @LvW OK, I'm listening to your opinion.

Comment: @Sitward To calculate the actual closed loop gain at any frequency use the formula Vout/Vin=Aol/(1+beta * Aol) where Aol is the open loop gain at the frequency of interest, beta is the feedback fraction and (1+beta * Aol) is the feedback factor. Remember , when using this formula,  that you must include the angle of the open loop gain in the formula.